# Защита от частых запросов к странице

Tags: php, html, apache, сервер

Доброго времени суток. Есть сайт, который работает по принципу file_get_contents. (берет информацию с Web Api). Есть проблема. При быстром нажатии на F5, сайт зависает на некоторое время, т.к. наверное не справляется с нагрузками.
Возможно ли как-то снизить нагрузку на страницы, где используется данная функция? Если будет много людей сидеть на сайте, то мне кажется он вообще взорвётся.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Код вывода информации:
https://gist.github.com/Xhonor/f6720ec44eef783af9625dcf31d62950

Код откуда берётся информация:
https://gist.github.com/Xhonor/469ba3f45d6660049d5e7e81a5a03bba

Всё работает на Steam Web Api

Comment: Нужно оптмизировать код (удивлены, да?) -- а для этого нужно этот код показать (удивлены, да?), желательно сразу показывайте кусок, который по замерам больше всего времени съедает.

Comment: Ых, побуду немного телепатом! Судя по странице вы все параметры профиля вычисляете на лету, даже всякие тяжеловесные и такое слово как "закешировать значения на полчаса" не слышали?

Comment: Вы так говорите, как будто я профессиональный программист и просто дурачка включил. Я всего-лишь любитель, которому нужен совет.

Comment: Какая именно часть кода вам нужна? Где выводится результат или как берется информация с сайта?

Comment: Да, я буду говорить с вами как с профессиональным программистом. Уверяю, это гораздо быстрее подымет вас по лестнице профессионализма, чем разжёвывание.

Comment: Насчёт фрагмента кода. Замерьте, куда уходит основное время при генерации страницы. Это раз. Убедите, что у вас хостинг достаточными ресурсами обладает, а не однодолларовый шаред, где на одном сервере триста клиентов свои сайты пасёт. Это два. И третье. Любые проблемы с производительностью можно залить кешированием, не вникая в подробности, что там и где тормозит. Второй раз уже не будет тормозить, а вас же это сейчас волнует, верно? Это три.

Comment: Добавил ссылки на коды. Посмотрите пожалуйста)

Comment: Хостинг reg.ru - думаю хороший.

Comment: Думаю, в данном случае вам нужно прямо перед `file_get_contents` записывать сессионную переменную "скрипт занят", которую в конце скрипта сбрасывать. Тогда при обновлении страницы скрипт будет видеть эту переменную и не будет запускать новый `file_get_contents`

Comment: Замерьте общее время генерации страницы - раз. У вас ~ пяток обращений к внешнему сервису, видимо там и будут основные тормоза по получению информации. Остальное не должно вносить особо много -- хотя я не читал весь код, у вас столько копипасты, что скроллил на автомате. Не знаю, может вам не говорили -- но когда вы делаете копию строки с elseif и меняете названия в двух местах -- это не совсем программирование.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такая штука, называеться `network latency` - время потраченое на путешествие по проводу.
Это очень медленно, и чем больше расстояние тем медленнее(скорость света). Даже если сравнивать скорость доступа к `localhost` и рядом стояшему такому же компьютеру. Разница в скорости запроса будет до 20 мс.

Подозреваю `steam` хостит свои api сервера на немалом ростоянии от вашего провайдера, т.е. Каждый запрос вам будет обходиться в лучшем случае 100мс в одну сторону.

Сгонять туда обратно - 200мс(оптимистично), это для каждого! запроса к `api`. Простая математика говорит что более 5 запросов в секунду не проделаешь.

Поменять код что бы делать меньше запросов к `api`. Хранить информацию в сессии или кэше...

Кэш - `memcached`, `redis`. Эти приложения позволяют хранить данные определенное время(полчаса например).

С сессией тяжелее, самому надо будет временем управлять.

Пример:

```
<?php>

// Псевдо код для понимания а не копирования!!!
function getUserInfo($userId)
{
    // Пробуем читать из кэша/сессии
    $userInfo = $cache->read("user_info_" . $userId);

    // Если в кэше нет
    if (!$userInfo) {
        // Читаем с api.
        $userInfo = $api->read("user_info_" . $userId);
        // Пишем в кэш на 30 минут 
        $cache->write("user_info_" . $userId, $userInfo, 30);
    }

    // Возвращаем значение.
    return $userInfo;
}

// Пишем информацию о пользователе
function setUserInfo($userId, $userInfo) {
    // Пишем новые значения в api.
    $api->write("user_info_" . $userId, $userInfo);
    // Пишем новые значения в кэш. Важно что бы небыло старых данных
    $cache->write("user_info_" . $userId, $userInfo, 30);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Сложно для меня, но я попробую)

Comment: А как думаете, может попробовать добавлять данные в mysql, если новый пользователь нашелся? И добавить кнопку обновить данные (раз в час например).

Comment: @Xhonor Любой способ, который уменьшает количество запросов, будет хорош. MySQL в таком случае тоже кэш, только более медленный (если с memcache, redis) сравнивать, но явно быстрее API. Да и кнопка подойдет, от приложения зависит.