# php парсер xml файла

Tags: php, xml, парсер

Есть xml файл[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал парсер и скрипт, который впоследствии добавляет товары в бы, но он долго работает, а если записей в xml файле больше, то вовсе не успевает до конца сработать.

```
    $languages = simplexml_load_file("test.xml", null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($languages->groupProduct as $group) {

        if((string) $group['name'] == "01 Плитка") {

            foreach ($group->element_list->element as $element) {

                $data = array(); //массив данных


                $file_name = date('YmdHis').rand(100,1000);

                $data["img"] = $file_name.".jpeg";

                foreach($element->minpart_list->minpart as $minpart) 
                    $data["description"] .= $minpart."<br />";                      

                if ($this->add($data)) {
                    $this->download_remote_file($element->pic, "../".$this->config->dir_img_products.$data["img"]);
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }           
    }

    function download_remote_file($file_url, $save_to) {
        $content = file_get_contents($file_url);
        file_put_contents($save_to, $content);
    }
```

как можно увеличить работоспособность скрипта?

Comment: как вариант увеличьте `max_execution_time` в настройках пхп

Answer (score 3):

Просто качайте файлы через curl_multi в несколько потоков ([пример](https://bitbucket.org/hardworm/provider_parser/src/9755dc4937a91472f819580b6241b87ea6151ab8/providerRSS/intercon_rss.php?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)).

Comment: Вариант, хороший, но хватит ли ширины канала и памяти?

Comment: Вот с вангованием у меня плохо. Пробовать надо. В канал полюбому будете упираться при большом  количестве потоков (поэтому качать надо ночью) или подбирать количество потоков. По памяти так же надо подбирать. Скорее всего упретесь в количество одновременных подключений к серверу ftp и до нехватки канала, а тем более не хватку памяти просто не дойдете.

Answer (score 2):

Да всё простo, у вас(вашего провайдера) фтп медленный. Что вас убивает network latency.

Читайте [Защита от частых запросов к странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/617418/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5/617485#617485).
Таже проблема у человека была.

**У вас несколько вариантов.**

1. Увеличить время скрипта. (Ни чего не решит.)
2. Использовать очередь работ. (RabbitMq, ZeroMQ ...). Главный скрипт скидывает работы, а качают фоновые скрипты.

http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html

http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:_start